# Validating Arguments to a Function

Tags: elisp, functions, variables, arguments, lisp

I would like to validate the argument to a function before its action is executed. The main concern is the passing of a void variable. How can I trap this?

```
(defun is-it-bound(item)
  (if (boundp 'item)
      (message "bound")
    (message "not bound")))
```

This doesn't work if I pass in a non-existent/undefined variable. Instead of getting "not bound", I get the "void-variable" explosion immediately. I want something like exception handling, so that I can trap the error.

I tried `condition-case` but the results are the same.

```
(defun is-it-bound(item)
  (condition-case nil
      (boundp 'item)
    (void-variable "%s" "void variable!" )
      ))
```

It looks like the argument is evaluated before being passed into the function. Is that correct?

In other languages, this is a no-brainer. But here, I need help getting it sorted. It's a brainer for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in Emacs Lisp, as in Common Lisp and most other Lisps, arguments are evaluated before evaluating the body of the function.

This is called *"applicative"* order evaluation. The opposite (passing the args unevaluated to the body, which evaluates them only as needed) is called *"normal"* order evaluation. (Well, there are actually multiple kinds of evaluation "as needed", but that's a detail here.)

Among other things, this means that you can end up with "wrong" (that is, perhaps unexpected) answers or infinite evaluation with Lisp.  As one example, you can't define **`if`** as a function (you can define it as a macro, as Lisp macros don't evaluate their args before evaluating the body): each of the "consequence" args gets evaluated before the body of the function.

---

But I sense that you might have another question behind this one.  That is, I suspect this is an [X-Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Instead of trying to figure out how to do what you think you need to do, try asking how to do what you really want to do. ;-)

You say that your *"main concern is the passing of a void variable."* As you've seen, that's impossible - the function itself binds the arguments as local variables.  Try to express your concern as a (separate) question.

---

Note that if what you want to do is *"pass a variable"*, and not pass the variable's value, then you can do that in either of these ways. The first (use a function) is almost always preferable.

1. Have callers of the function pass `'the-variable`, not just `the-variable` to it. Quoting means that when the function is called it's passed the result of evaluating the quoted symbol, which is the symbol (`the-variable`).  Note that the function can do whatever it wants with the symbol, including, but not limited to, treating it as a variable.
2. Define a macro instead of a function.  The macro body need not evaluate the variable passed to it as argument.  (The macro body can do whatever else you want, to produce code that then gets evaluated.)